# Postgresql intarray error: undefined symbol: pfree

Tags: postgresql, greenplum

I'm trying to install Postgresql (8.2.15) [additional supplied modules](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/contrib.html) intarray and intagg for my Greenplum database 4.2.1.0. The installation seems successful; I followed the tutorial [here](http://sayap.com/blog/2010/3/11/installing-a-contrib-module-for-greenplum) and all the files are copied into the greenplumlib-db-4.2.1.0/lib/postgresql share/postgresql directory. but when I tried to execute my java code, it throws an "undefined symbol" error:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: could not load library "/usr/local/greenplum-db-4.2.1.0/lib/postgresql/_int.so": /usr/local/greenplum-db-4.2.1.0/lib/postgresql/_int.so: undefined symbol: pfree
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2062)
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1795)
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:257)
at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:479)
at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:353)
at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:345)
at tuffy.db.RDB.execute(RDB.java:354)
at tuffy.db.RDB.resetSchema(RDB.java:700)
at felix.main.Felix.parseFelixQuery(Felix.java:106)
at felix.main.Felix.run(Felix.java:755)
at felix.main.Main.main(Main.java:69)
```

saying that the symbol **pfree** is undefined. I have checked the version number: both the postgresql in Greenplum and the additional module are 8.2.15. Am I missing something?

**Update**: The link to the tutorial seems unstable; it basically gives some simple steps to complete the installation:

```
Get any of the postgresql 8.2 source package from the official site
su - gpadmin
Unpack the source, then go to ~/postgresql-8.2.xx/contrib/xxx
make USE_PGXS=1 COPT="-Wno-error" install
(Optional for Greenplum MPP) Use gpssh to copy whatever .so file that just get installed       under /usr/local/greenplum-db/lib/postgresql to other nodes
psql -f xxx.sql [DBNAME]
```

**Update**:
Thank you for your answer.

I'm installing Greenplum, but it only includes postgresql 8.2.15, so I have to use this version. I have copied the whole /usr/local/pgsql/lib directory to the greenplum library, it seems to get the intarray to work, but now I have a new error:

```
could not load library "/usr/local/greenplum-db-4.2.1.0/lib/postgresql/plpgsql.so":
/usr/local/greenplum-db-4.2.1.0/lib/postgresql/plpgsql.so: undefined symbol: heap_copytuple
```

It seems that I'm missing some files...

Thank you!

Comment: Exactly what did yo download from where, in terms of the extension?

Comment: I downloaded the Greenplum database [here](http://www.greenplum.com/community/downloads/database-ce/) and Postgresql 8.2.15 [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pgsql/files/PostgreSQL%208.2.X/). But never mind, I'll try the newest Postgresql instead. Thank you all for your answers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have missed that [PostgreSQL 8.2 has reached end of life in 2011](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/).

Upgrade to a more current version, (latest is 9.1 at the time of writing), where installing the extension (formerly: "additional supplied modules") [intarray](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/intarray.html) is a matter of:

```
CREATE EXTENSION intarray;
```

[The manual about `CREATE EXTENSION`.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createextension.html)