# postgresql find common patterns of minimum length between strings

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm using postgresql 9.3 and I'm trying to `inner join` two tables on common string patterns of a minimum length.

Also I'm a noob to SQL try to be patient if possible.

For example:

```
TABLE 1

ID        DATA
1         '1234,5678,1234,1111'
2         '1111,2222'
3         '4321'



TABLE 2

IDa        DATA
1a         '1111,2222,1234,5678,4321'
2a         '1111,3837,2222'
3a         '4321'
```

joining `DATA` column on strings matching more than 9 chars would yield:

```
IDa    ID     DATA
1a     2     '1111,2222'
1a     1     '1234,5678'
```

I had some success using `LIKE` but I can't force a minimum match length condition(or at least I don't know how). I'm assuming a regex is the solution here but I haven't been able to write one that accomplished what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your examples match on 2 x 4 characters, not `more than 9 chars`.

I suggest using array types (`int[]`) instead of character types, in combination with the handy [intersection operator **`&`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/intarray.html#INTARRAY-OP-TABLE) from the [additional module intarray](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/intarray.html). More details:
 - [Error when creating unaccent extension on PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12100638/error-when-creating-unaccent-extension-on-postgresql/12101055#12101055)
 - [Postgresql intarray error: undefined symbol: pfree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10491184/postgresql-intarray-error-undefined-symbol-pfree/10491433#10491433)

Query could look like this

```
SELECT t2.ida, t1.id, t1.data & t2.data AS intersecting_data
FROM   tbl1 t1
JOIN   tbl2 t2 ON array_length(t1.data & t2.data, 1) = 2; -- or "> 1" ?
```

Not very efficient, this kind of cross join does not scale well.

#### Normalize

Faster alternative: a normalized schema with 1 row per data item. Then the operation boils down to a [relational-division](/questions/tagged/relational-division).

```
tbl1_data

tbl1_id  item
1        1234
1        5678
1        1234
1        1111
2        1111
...

tbl2_data

tbl1_id  item
1a       1111
1a       2222
...
```

Then the query could be:

```
SELECT tbl1_id, tbl2_id, array_agg(item) AS data
FROM   tbl1_data d1
JOIN   tbl2_data d2 USING (item)
GROUP  BY 1,2
HAVING count(*) = 2;  --  or "> 1" ?
```